# Дополнительные подсказки в Sublime Text 3

Tags: css, sublime-text

Появились непонятным образом какие-то дополнительные подсказки при редактировании css файлов, постоянно мешают.

[image: Доп. подсказка]

Подсказки по умолчанию остались и с ними все ок, но это что?

Comment: Приложите список установленных плагинов

Comment: @Voprositel AutoFileName, Color Highlighter, Color Scheme - Thunderstorm, Dark Neon Color Scheme, Emmet, LiveReload, LocalizedMenu, One Dark Material - Theme, Package Control, Sass, SCSS, W3CValidators

Comment: это emmet
если хочешь удали через Crel+Shift+P
Remove Package и выбераешь Emmet